# Converting different columns to a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, datetime-format

The time in my csv file is divided into 4 columns, (year, julian day, hour/minut(utc) and second), and I wanted to convert to a single column so that it looks like this: 14/11/2017 00:16:00.

Is there a easy way to do this?

A sample of the code is

```
cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
D14 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\William Jacondino\Desktop\DadosTimeSeries\PIRATA-PROFILE\Dados FLUXO\Dados_brutos_copy-20220804T151840Z-002\Dados_brutos_copy\tm_data_2017_11_14_0016.dat', header=None, usecols=cols, names=["Year","Julian day", "Hour/minut (UTC)", "Second", "Bateria (V)", "PTemp (°C)", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Magnectic_Variation (arb)", "Altitude (m)", "Course (º)", "WS", "Nmbr_of_Satellites (arb)", "RAD", "Tar", "UR", "slp",], sep=',')
D14 = D14.loc[:, ["Year","Julian day", "Hour/minut (UTC)", "Second", "Latitude", "Longitude","WS", "RAD", "Tar", "UR", "slp"]]
```

My array looks like that:

[image: PRINT]

The file: [csv file sample](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvO08oBWX0Vtg9dlW1U3N1Xxy2SALg)

The "Hour/minut (UTC)" column has the first two digits referring to the Local Time and the last two digits referring to the minute.

The beginning of the time in the "Hour/minut (UTC)" column starts at 016 which refers to 0 hour UTC and minute 16.

and goes up to hour 12 UTC and minute 03.

I wanted to unify everything into a single datetime column so from the beginning to the end of the array:

1 - 2017

1412 - 14/11/2017 12:03:30

but the column "Hour/minut (UTC)" from hour 0 to hour 9 only has one value like this:
9
instead of 09

How do I create the array with the correct datetime?

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)), don't use images.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column which also adds the data from other columns.

For example, if you have a dataframe like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# Print df:

   year month  day  a  b  c
0  2010   jan    1  1  4  7
1  2010   feb    2  2  5  8
2  2020   mar    3  3  6  9
```

You can add a new column field on the DataFrame, with the values extracted from the Year Month and Date columns.

`df['newColumn'] = df.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.month + '-' + df.day.astype(str)`

Edit: In your situation instead of using `df.month` use `df['Julian Day']` since the column name is different. To understand more on why this is, [read here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)

The data in the new column will be as string with the way you like to format it. You can also substitute the dash `'-'` with a slash `'/'` or however you need to format the outcome. You just need to convert the integers into strings with `.astype(str)`

Output:

```py
   year month  day  a  b  c   newColumn
0  2010   jan    1  1  4  7  2010-jan-1
1  2010   feb    2  2  5  8  2010-feb-2
2  2020   mar    3  3  6  9  2020-mar-3
```

After that you can do anything as you would on a dataframe object.

If you only need it for data analysis you can do it with the function `.groupBy()` which groups the data fields and performs the analysis.
[source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe looks like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "year": [2017, 2017], "julian day": [318, 318], "hour/minut(utc)": [16, 16],
    "second": [0, 30],
})
```

```
   year  julian day  hour/minut(utc)  second
0  2017         318               16       0
1  2017         318               16      30
```

then you could use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pd.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to do

```
df["datetime"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df["year"].astype("str"), format="%Y")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["julian day"] - 1, unit="days")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["hour/minut(utc)"], unit="minutes")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["second"], unit="seconds")
).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

and get

```
   year  julian day  hour/minut(utc)  second             datetime
0  2017         318               16       0  14/11/2017 00:16:00
1  2017         318               16      30  14/11/2017 00:16:30
```

The column `datetime` now contains *strings*. Remove the `.dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` part at the end, if you want *datetimes* instead.

---

Regarding your comment: If I understand correctly, you could try the following:

```
df["hours_min"] = df["hour/minut(utc)"].astype("str").str.zfill(4)
df["hour"] = df["hours_min"].str[:2].astype("int")
df["minute"] = df["hours_min"].str[2:].astype("int")
df = df.drop(columns=["hours_min", "hour/minut(utc)"])

df["datetime"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df["year"].astype("str"), format="%Y")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["julian day"] - 1, unit="days")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["hour"], unit="hours")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["minute"], unit="minutes")
    + pd.to_timedelta(df["second"], unit="seconds")
).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Result for the sample dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "year": [2017, 2017, 2018, 2019], "julian day": [318, 318, 10, 50],
    "hour/minut(utc)": [16, 16, 234, 1201], "second": [0, 30, 1, 2],
})
```

```
   year  julian day  hour/minut(utc)  second
0  2017         318               16       0
1  2017         318               16      30
2  2018          10              234       1
3  2019          50             1201       2
```

would be

```
   year  julian day  second  hour  minute             datetime
0  2017         318       0     0      16  14/11/2017 00:16:00
1  2017         318      30     0      16  14/11/2017 00:16:30
2  2018          10       1     2      34  10/01/2018 02:34:01
3  2019          50       2    12       1  19/02/2019 12:01:02
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: My "Hour/minut (UTC)" column has the first two strings referring to hour and the other two referring to minute in the same column, do you know how I can separate the two? 

Hour/minut (UTC) has:

016

where 0 is 0 UTC and 16 is minutes. 

How can i split this? 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @WilliamJacondino I'm not completely sure about the input, but check my edit, maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, Timues! My column "hour/minut(utc)"

has two problems: 

The starting hour 0 through 9 only has one value, and starting at hour 10 it has two values in the column. I was trying to make the script understand that from hour 0 to hour 9 is only one value so that it doesn't take the last two digits that belong to the minute.

Comment: @WilliamJacondino Sorry, this is really hard to understand without a full set of examples: Could you edit them in your question? My current understanding for column `hour/minut(utc)`: `1` -> 1 minute, `10` -> 10 minutes, `111` -> 1 hour and 11 minutes, `1234` -> 12 hours and 34 minutes. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, Timus! I edit my question

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit. Now I got it here! Thank you very much, my friend!